# Builder has private access in Builder

Tags: java, builder

What's wrong with this Java code fragment?

```
ClientRegistration registration = new ClientRegistration.Builder(properties.getClientId())
        .authorizationUri(properties.getAuthorizationUri())
        .build();
```

I get the following error message but don't understand it:

```
error: Builder(String) has private access in Builder
        ClientRegistration registration = new ClientRegistration.Builder(properties.getClientId())
                                          ^
```

As far as I understand, this error normally results from code like this:

```
ClientRegistration registration = new ClientRegistration().Builder(properties.getClientId())
```

and the above code is the right solution for the problem. But now I have the problem the other way around.

any Idea?

Comment: Guessing the constructor that takes a string in that inner Builder class is private? And then: provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't guessing - it is code from a tutorial. Seems to be a pre-release code

Comment: btw: thanx for the hint. Builder(string) wasn't always private and the error message pointed me in the wrong direction.

Comment: again: thanx - I now understand that my problem wasn't the pattern (that's why I thought the provided code is enough) but the problem was the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ClientRegistration.Builder` can not be created with the `new` keyword because its constructor is private.

What you should be is:

```
ClientRegistration.Builder builder = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(registrationIdAsString)
```

This creates a new `ClientRegistration.Builder` for you.

Afterwards you can set your fields in the `ClientRegistration.Builder` and call `.build()` to get your `ClientRegistration`. Like that:

```
ClientRegistration registration = builder.authorizationUri(properties.getAuthorizationUri())
    .build();
```

Have a look at the JavaDocs of the builder to see what properties you can set:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistration.Builder.html

Alternatively in one line, like you did it:

```
ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(properties.getClientId())
    .authorizationUri(properties.getAuthorizationUri())
    .build();
```